# Is the product of a cubic threefold and the projective line irrational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let $Z$ be a very general smooth cubic threefold: as far as I know, whether $Z$ is stably rational or not is still an open problem.

I was wondering instead if it is known that $Z \times \mathbb P^1$ is irrational.
If so, is there a reference for this?

Comment: No, it is not known.

Comment: Thank you very much! @abx